Matching Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition with the respective Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax
Given a Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition instance and a Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxTree instance is there a library that allows to locate inside the syntax tree the matching Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.BaseMethodDeclarationSyntax node?
This is not a trivial task, implicit constructors do not even have the respective base method node in the syntax tree, but it is possible to define something reasonable. And one has to correctly map property getters/setters, event adders/removers, destructor and the various operators.
I was unable to find such a library, the search is made difficult by a lot of false positives.
Does anyone know of such a library?
